# what is ethloader, and how can I download the source

Tags: linux

I'm having problem on finding program called ethloader. Would anybody tell me how to download it? And, where can I download the source.

When I tried to run that application without parameter, the following usage is shown:

[code]

./ethloader "<"hostname/">" "<"mac address">"

```
-f=<name>     upload a file to flash memory
-k=<kernel>   upload kernel image to flash memory
-r=<ramdisk>  upload ramdisk image to flash memory

[-b=<block>]  indicate starting flash memory block
[-m=<size>]   indicate maximum file size in hex number
[-s=<size>]   indicate maximum flash memory size in hex number
```

[/code]

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 0):

```
 Usage of ethloader:
 ethloader <ip> <mac> -f=<filename> -b=<offset>
  <ip>:if your ip is 192.168.2.1 ,you should set this ip to 192.168.2.X (X =1~254)
  <mac>: 86:95:0a:12:34:bc
  <filename>:The file name of the flashimage 
  <offset>:If your flashimage is 4 MB,the offset should set to 0.
  example:ethloader 192.168.2.100 86:95:0a:12:34:bc -f=flashimage -b=0
```

source: http://ftp.dlink.ru/pub/Multimedia/DSM-320/Firmware/Ethloader%280506113200%29.txt